# How do I change team member role on Slack via API?

Tags: slack-api

does anyone know if it's possible to change a team member's role on Slack via API, e.g. promote user from `member` to `admin`?

The docs at https://api.slack.com/methods don't help much. Is this part of their SCIM API offering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned the basic Slack API does not provide a method for setting the role of a user.

The SCIM API appears to support this feature with PATCH /Users/{id} according to the [official documentation](https://api.slack.com/scim). However, I am using the free tier and have no means to verify this.

There might be an undocumented method though, that provides this functionality. Should you find one, I would appreciate it if you could add it to this github repository of all known [undocumented Slack API methods](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc).

Comment: After a bit of trying there seam to be an undocumented method called `users.admin.setAdmin`. Not sure yet how it works though